# iOS: link error while aginst a static lib, even if I didn't reference any code from that lib

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, static-linking

I included libzar.a in my project, however, even if I didn't write any code to reference any methods in libzar, my project still failed to link. Here's error output,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
```

"_CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane", referenced from:
      -[ZBarCVImage convertCVtoRGB] in libxxx.a(ZBarCVImage.o)

"_CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane", referenced from:
      -[ZBarCVImage convertCVtoRGB] in libxxx.a(ZBarCVImage.o)

"_CVPixelBufferGetHeight", referenced from:
      -[ZBarCVImage convertCVtoRGB] in libxxx.a(ZBarCVImage.o)

"_CVPixelBufferGetWidth", referenced from:
      -[ZBarCVImage convertCVtoRGB] in libxxx.a(ZBarCVImage.o)

"_CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress", referenced from:
      -[ZBarCVImage convertCVtoRGB] in libxxx.a(ZBarCVImage.o)

"_CVPixelBufferRelease", referenced from:
      -[ZBarCVImage setPixelBuffer:] in libxxx.a(ZBarCVImage.o)

"_CVPixelBufferRetain", referenced from:
      -[ZBarCVImage setPixelBuffer:] in libxxx.a(ZBarCVImage.o)

"_CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress", referenced from:
      -[ZBarCVImage convertCVtoRGB] in libxxx.a(ZBarCVImage.o)

"_iconv", referenced from:
      _qr_code_data_list_extract_text in libxxx.a(qrdectxt.o)

"_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _qr_code_data_list_extract_text in libxxx.a(qrdectxt.o)

"_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _qr_code_data_list_extract_text in libxxx.a(qrdectxt.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here's what I did,
  1. just added libzar.a to my project
  2. built app
  3. error

My linking configuration was only added -all_load and -ObjC options. Traditionally, if I never reference any code from a static library, it would never be such linking errors. Did I miss sth?

Comment: Have you imported the files required from lib file into the class, where you are using the functions???

Comment: I didn't use any methods from the lib. I just imported all header files and the static lib, I believe it's the right way to use a third party library. I'm curious why Xcode failed to link even if I didn't have any references for libzar but just imported it.

Comment: add this line in your class file {"#import "ZBarImageScanner.h"}. Import it where you are using scanner code. I hope it'll resolve your issue.

Comment: Are you creating project for reading bar code?? If yes, Then please follow this link & download the sample project here: https://github.com/WillChilcutt/Barcode-Reader It'll solve your issue.

Comment: I just encountered the same issue. I solved it by: Go to Project Navigator, select my `.a` library. On the right pane, select tab Show the File Inspector. Then, make sure the box is checked for Target Membership. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Adding CoreVideo.framework to your 'Link Binary With Libraries' build phase should clear that up.